# YouTube commentThreads limiting comment replies to 5 results in JSON data?

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I've built a PHP script to pull all comments (by iterating all result pages), and their replies. It's working fine, except the replies seem to be capped at 5 results.

```
items->replies->comments
```

...this will only have 5 results in the JSON data, even when `items->snippet->totalReplyCount` is higher than 5.

Here's the call I'm using:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key={KEY}&part=snippet,replies&maxResults=100&videoId={VIDEO}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Link is not working because you have no api-key. What did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: stvar's reply was the answer I needed. Thanks!

Comment: For the future, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads) (emphasis below is mine):

> A `commentThread` resource contains information about a YouTube comment thread, which comprises a *top-level comment* and *replies*, if any exist, to that comment. A `commentThread` resource can represent comments about either a video or a channel.
>
> Both the top-level comment and the replies are actually [`comment`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments) resources nested inside the `commentThread` resource. *The `commentThread` resource does not necessarily contain all replies to a comment, and you need to use the [`Comments.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) method if you want to retrieve all replies for a particular comment*. Also note that some comments do not have replies.

Therefore, if you want to obtain all top-level comments and each of their associated replies you have to combine the two endpoints `CommentThreads.list` and `Comments.list` in two loops:

1. obtain all top-level comments;
2. for each such top-level comment, get all its attached replies.

The way you combine these loops is up to you (nota bene: both of these API endpoints provide paginated result sets).